# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)\cos^2(nt) \,dt$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, fourier-series

Let $f \in C[-\pi,\pi]$.

Find the following limit:

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)\cos^2(nt)\,dt$$

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Have you tried anything yet?  Is this from class/for homework?  If so, are there any tricks you went over recently that might apply here?

Comment: Check [Lebesgue -Riemann lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma).

Comment: In addition to Mhenni's comment, note that $\cos^2(nt) = \frac 12 \left(1 + \cos(2nt)\right)$

Comment: @user121418 There is a variation of the lemma that holds for Fourier series (that is, holds over $[-\pi, \pi]$. Check the wiki article.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\cos^2 nx=\frac{1+\cos  2nx}{2},
$$
and hence
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\,\cos^2 nx\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\,dx+
\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\,\cos 2nx\,dx
$$
The second integral tends to zero due to [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma), and hence
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\,\cos^2 nx\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\,dx.
$$